# Does copper react with hydrochloric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

In my chemistry lab, we had 18 different reactions involving many different substances. One of the experiments involved placing a piece of copper metal in hydrochloric acid.

While observing it for a minute, my partner and I did not notice any reaction taking place. However, a minute was all we were allowed, and we could not keep it longer to observe it.

It was the only experiment that looked like it had no reaction, so I felt a little uneasy putting it down. (I didn't do anything wrong, but I guess I was unsure with myself).

I have seen some sources say that no reaction is the current result. However, I have also seen some sources saying that it does react, via $\ce{Cu + 2HCl -> CuCl2 + H2}$, yielding cupric chloride and dihydrogen gas.

Which is the correct result? If no reaction is correct, what would be the correct chemical reaction for this case?

Comment: The correct result?  Are you going to argue with observable reality?

Comment: @AbelFriedman well, I guess I am concerned that a reaction was occurring at a slow pace that I did not have the time to observe. And the fact that sites say that a reaction should occur.

Comment: @erdekhayser this may be helpful http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/copper-doesnt-react-with-hydrochloric-acid

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Thanks! That is very informative.